# mystery dog / bear / husky icon in taskbar

Tags: taskbar, icons

Can anyone help me figure out what program this icon is for?
When I click it, it doesn't show any information. 
It's a school laptop.
I've tried looking in programs and can't find anything.

Here is a screenshot of the icon:

[image: Screenshot of taskbar icon]

Comment: If its a school computer, ask your school IT. It looks like a product for computer management called "Deep Freeze", but only your IT support staff will know for certain.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bear.  It's the icon for Faronics Deep Freeze program. 
https://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/enterprise

Here's the image from their website: [image]

And a screenshot of it in the taskbar:
[image]